# How to check if content of CSV file follows a specific format in Python?

Tags: python, csv, assert

I am creating a python program that take a CSV file as an input (location of file as command-line) and before doing any preprocessing, it asserts if the content of the file is in specific format and if not, raise an exception to the user stating choose correct files.

The content should be something like this:

```
Sr.no .  Codes .  v1 .     v2 .     v3 .     v4 .   ... v300
1 .      code1 .  val1 .   val2 .   val3 .   NA .   ... NA
2 .      code2 .  val4 .   NA .     NA .     NA .   ... NA
3 .      code3 .  val5 .   val6 .   NA .     NA .   ... NA
4 .      code4 .  val7 .   val8 .   val9 .   NA .   ... NA
.
.
```

Basically it should be a CSV file, with first two columns as SrNo. and Codes and next 300 columns as some values, followed by 'NA' up to 300.

If user uploads something like this

```
Sr.no .  Codes .  v1 .     v2 .      v3 .    . . . . . v300
1 .      code1 .  NA .     val1 .    NA .    . . . . . NA 
2 .      code2 .  val2 .   val3 .    NA .    . . . . . NA
```

It should raise an exception as in line with Srno=1, there is a value, in column v2 despite having NA in column v1.

Want to know, how I can assert if the content of file is in this format using Python(a sample code snippet would be helpful). Also sources from where I can learn how to assert file content content for not just this format but generic formats as well.

For now, I have reached up to here, and need to complete assert_format function

```
import sys
import csv

def assert_format(file_name):

    csv_file = open(file_name)
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    #code to check format

    return True

file_name = sys.argv[1]

if assert_format(file_name):
    print("format is correct")
else:
    print("choose correct file")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You obviously need a `for row in reader:`, or maybe `for srno, codes, *vs in reader:` Then, inside that loop, you write whatever the logic is. I'm not sure what your rule is, but I think it involves `srno` being something you can successfully call `int` on (which you can test by just using `try`/`except` around `int`), and something like `first_na = vs.index('NA')` and then `all(val == 'NA' for val in vs[first_na:])` (with proper handling for `index` raising because there are no `NA`s). If that's not enough to get you unstuck, you need to provide your actual rule, and how you tried to code it.

Comment: Meanwhile, you're never closing the file, which you really should. The best way to do it is to replace that `csv_file = open(file_name)` with `with open(file_name) as csv_file:`.

Comment: One more thing: the default dialect for `csv.reader` expects commas as separators, not periods. (CSV stands for "comma-separated values.) So you'll need to pass the right arguments to specify your actual dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this fits your requirement:

```
import sys
import csv
def assert_format(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='.')
        for row in reader:
            flag=False
            for cell in row:
                if(cell == 'NA' and not flag):
                        flag=True
                elif(cell == 'NA' and flag):
                        return False
    return True

file_name = sys.argv[1]

if assert_format(file_name):
    print("format is correct")
else:
    print("choose correct file")
```

Comment: Thank you, This worked for me. Wanted to know, if this is the only possible way, as this is kind of hardcoding things. What if I want something like expecting a set of integer before NA, or expecting a set of strings before NA in the columns I have?

Comment: You can use regular expressions for pattern match. As this was example so i matched fixed sting. You can match pattern and use the Boolean response from it as condition check instead.